# how to configure vmware esxi host to send logs to ibm qradar

Tags: vmware, syslog, esxi, vcenter, qradar

I have qradar setup on one host and vmware vsphere cloud setup on another host.
My Vsphere cloud setup has one esxi host
I want to send logs from of this esxi host to my qradar.
How to do it.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to vSphere Web Client
2. Click on Esxi host that you want to send logs to qradar
3. Go to Configure -> Advance System Setting
4. Click edit and filter keyword 'Syslog.global.logHost'
5. put value as 'udp://:514' in 'Syslog.global.logHost' field.Click OK.
6. Go to Configure -> Firewall
7. Click edit and filter keyword 'syslog'
8. Checked the syslog check box.Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add information on point 8, the firewall menu can be accessed via the network tab to restrict access through the firewall